Newton's Equation in Polar Coordinates: The Hard Way
Everyone is familiar discussing traditional "$ \vec F = m\vec a $" problems in polar coordinates from elementary physics classes.
Now, I'm learning some affine and Riemannian geometry: (Koszul's) connections, covariant derivatives and parallel transport along curves, geodesics etc. (mostly at the level of Lee's book).
I find these concepts a bit hard to grasp, because they're being presented to me in a very mathy/abstract way. At the same time, I feel that all this covariant differentiation/parallel transport business is strongly related to those boring computations we do in an elementary mechanics class when we deal with moving/rotating frames of reference and change of coordinates thereof.
Indeed, Newtonian Mechanics goes like this. Take a Riemannian manifold $ (M,\mathbf g) $ and denote with $ {\nabla} $ the Levi-Civita connection on $ M $. Given a "force" vector field $ F\in \mathscr X(M) $, the motion is governed by the differential equation
$$
\nabla_\dot x{\dot x} = F\circ x
$$
where $ x\colon I\subset \mathbb R\to M $ is some smooth curve defined on an interval.
My question is basically this one: could anyone provide me an example where al this affine/Riemannian technology is used in the Newtonian mechanics of rotating reference frames?
For example, how can I phrase the usual argument that allows me to write the acceleration vector $ \vec a(t)\in \mathbb R^{3} $ of a particle in $ \mathbb R^3 $ in polar coordinates using these "modern" tools?

You may find the DG concepts a bit easier to grasp when you convert the Euclidean metric into polar coordinates and calculate its Christoffel symbols. Start with 2D then go to 3D. Slightly tedious but standard calculus. Modern DG has not freed us from doing those calculations when we want to see the abstract concepts in action. With sympy you can study every Riemannian metric in 2D and 3D. It calculates Christoffel symbols, Riemann and Ricci tensors.

Your questions don’t really have to do with Newton’s second law per se, because you’re asking questions about kinematics (how to express various velocities/accelerations in terms of other quantities) whereas Newton’s second law (once an $F$ is prescribed) gives you a system of differential equations to solve (with certain initial conditions), i.e it gives the dynamics.
So, let’s completely ignore Newton’s second law. What you’re really asking about is how to express various quantities (namely certain derivatives) in terms of a certain frame (in your case, the rotating frame from say polar coordinates). The Christoffel symbols, or what amounts to the same information, the connection 1-forms relative to our chosen frame, were tailor made to answer this question. In this answer, I shall mainly focus on the 1-forms perspective, because this is the variant I think is more directly visible in physics (especially when dealing with rotational mechanics). I suggest you look at the following answers of mine:

Relation between "method of moving frames", spin connection, Cartan forms, and classic rotational kinematics in $\mathbb{E}^n$. I suggest you read this now so you can follow along/get the definitions of what I’m about to say below.
Notation confusion about time derivative of a vector in a rotating frame, for an answer at a lower level, without any DG vocabulary.


1. Connection 1-forms for polar coordinates
As a concrete example, let us consider the manifold $M=\Bbb{R}^2$ with its usual Riemannian metric $g=dx^2+dy^2$, and the corresponding Levi-Civita connection. Note that this is just the usual flat connection on a vector space (so the covariant derivative $\nabla_XY$ is just the usual directional derivative $D_XY$ where $X,Y$ are treated as $\Bbb{R}^2$-valued smooth functions; and so $\nabla Y=dY$, where the latter is the usual vector-valued exterior derivative).
Next, let $U$ be an open subset on which polar coordinates $(r,\theta)$ are defined (I’ll let you generalize to $\Bbb{R}^3$ and spherical coordinates, or cylindrical coordinates). Then, the metric is
\begin{align}
g=dr^2+r^2\,d\theta^2,
\end{align}
and so we have the orthonormal coframe $\{\epsilon^r,\epsilon^{\theta}\}$ with  $\epsilon^r=dr$ and $\epsilon^{\theta}=r\,d\theta$. This is the dual basis to the orthonormal frame $\{e_r,e_{\theta}\}$ that is explicitly given as $e_r=\frac{\partial}{\partial r},e_{\theta}=\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}$ (in Physics, these are typically written as $\{\hat{r},\hat{\theta}\}$ with boldface… but I don’t feel like typing that).
Now, the connection $1$-forms $(\omega^i_{\,j})$ relative to the orthonormal frame $\{e_r,e_{\theta}\}$, which are a-priori defined via the equation $d(e_j)=\omega^i_{\,j}\,e_i$, are in fact the unique collection of 1-forms such that

$\omega^i_{\,j}=-\omega^j_{\,i}$
$d\epsilon^i=-\omega^i_{\,j}\wedge\epsilon^j$.

The first bullet point is an easy consequence of orthonormality of $\{e_r,e_{\theta}\}$, by applying $d$ to $g(e_i,e_j)=0$, using the definition $d(e_j)=\omega^i_{\,j}\,e_i$ and then juggling a few indices. The second equation is a consequence of the fact that the connection $\nabla$ is torsion-free (it is called Cartan’s (first) structural equation (for torsion)). So, by the first bullet point, we can write for some $1$-form $\beta$,
\begin{align}
(\omega^i_{\,j})&=
\begin{pmatrix}
0&\beta\\
-\beta&0
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align}
By the second bullet point, we must have
\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix}
d\epsilon^r\\
d\epsilon^{\theta}
\end{pmatrix}
&=
-\begin{pmatrix}
0&\beta\\
-\beta&0
\end{pmatrix}\wedge
\begin{pmatrix}
\epsilon^r\\
\epsilon^{\theta}
\end{pmatrix},
\end{align}
and so plugging in $\epsilon^r=dr$ and $\epsilon^{\theta}=r\,d\theta$, we see that
\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
dr\wedge d\theta
\end{pmatrix}&=
\begin{pmatrix}
-\beta\wedge r\,d\theta\\
\beta\wedge dr
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align}
This system of equations has the unique solution $\beta=-d\theta$. Thus, the connection 1-forms are
\begin{align}
(\omega^i_{\,j})&=
\begin{pmatrix}
\omega^r_{\,r}&\omega^r_{\,\theta}\\
\omega^{\theta}_{\,r}&\omega^{\theta}_{\,\theta}
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
0&-d\theta\\
d\theta&0
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align}
Here’s some foreshadowing: on the one hand, the connection 1-forms are also called the Ricci rotation forms, and as you can read in the first link in Cartan’s own words, he calls these the components of rotation (of a trihedron). On the other hand, you know from years of experience that the quantity $\dot{\theta}$ is intimately tied to angular velocity in the plane. So, it is no surprise at all that these 1-forms have purely $d\theta$ appearing in them.
Let us continue mathematically. Now that we have the connection 1-forms, we can explicitly write out the derivatives of the orthonormal frame:
\begin{align}
\begin{cases}
d(e_r)&=d\theta\,\otimes e_{\theta}\\
d(e_{\theta})&= -d\theta\,\otimes e_{r}
\end{cases}.
\tag{$@$}
\end{align}
(I personally would omit the $\otimes$ symbol when writing this, and will do so henceforth).
Let $N$ be any smooth manifold and let $f:N\to U\subset M$ be any smooth map. Let $\xi_r=e_r\circ f=f^*(e_r)$ and $\xi_{\theta}=e_{\theta}\circ f=f^*(e_{\theta})$. Then, pulling back the above equations by $f$ gives
\begin{align}
\begin{cases}
d\xi_r&=d(\theta\circ f)\,\xi_{\theta}\\
d\xi_{\theta}&=-d(\theta\circ f)\,\xi_r.
\end{cases}
\end{align}
Now, for any smooth lift $X$ of $f$ to $TM$ (i.e a ‘vector field along $f$’, or explicitly, a smooth map $X:N\to TM$ such that $\pi_{TM\to M}\circ X=f$), we can decompose it as $X=X^r\xi_r+X^{\theta}\xi_{\theta}$ for some smooth functions $X^r,X^{\theta}:N\to\Bbb{R}$. Now, we can compute the vector-valued exterior derivative of $X$ to get
\begin{align}
dX&= d(X^r)\cdot \xi_r+ X^r\cdot (d(\theta\circ f)\,\xi_{\theta})+ d(X^{\theta})\,\xi_{\theta}+ X^{\theta}\cdot (-d(\theta\circ f)\,\xi_r)\\
&=\bigg(dX^r-X^{\theta}\cdot d(\theta\circ f)\bigg)\xi_r+\bigg(dX^{\theta}+X^r\cdot d(\theta\circ f)\bigg)\,\xi_{\theta}\tag{$*$}
\end{align}
In general index notation, this says $dX=(dX^i+\omega^i_{\,j}X^j)\,\xi_i$, as I described in my first link. Notice that this is the source of the formulae you encounter in physics books when they talk about relating ‘time derivatives in fixed frame vs body frame’ (see my second link where I explain this with less DG lingo).
Now, we extract special cases of this formula: let $N=I$ be an open interval and $f=\gamma:I\to U$ a smooth curve. Now, since the domain is an interval all these 1-forms on $I$ will be a multiple of $dt$, so we can ‘divide’ by it on both sides (or more precisely, evaluate both sides on the vector field $\frac{d}{dt}$ in order to extract the coefficient).

Then, applying the above formula to the velocity $\dot{\gamma}=(r\circ\gamma)’\cdot\xi_r+ (r\circ\gamma)\cdot(\theta\circ\gamma)’\,\xi_{\theta}$ playing the role of $X$, we get
\begin{align}
\frac{d\dot{\gamma}}{dt}&=\bigg((r\circ\gamma)’’- (r\circ\gamma)(\theta\circ\gamma)’\cdot (\theta\circ\gamma)’\bigg)\xi_r
+\bigg([(r\circ\gamma)\cdot (\theta\circ\gamma)’]’+(r\circ\gamma)\cdot(\theta\circ\gamma)’\bigg)\,\xi_{\theta}\\
&=\bigg((r\circ\gamma)’’-(r\circ\gamma)[(\theta\circ\gamma)’]^2\bigg)\,\xi_r+
\bigg((r\circ\gamma)(\theta\circ\gamma)’’+2(r\circ\gamma)’(\theta\circ\gamma)’\bigg)\,\xi_{\theta}.
\end{align}
Or, adopting the classical notation of not writing out the composition with $\gamma$, and writing $\hat{\mathbf{r}}=\xi_r,\hat{\mathbf{\theta}}=\xi_{\theta}$ (again, even though originally $\hat{\mathbf{r}},\hat{\mathbf{\theta}}$ were originally defined on all of $U$), we get the well-known formula for the acceleration in polar coordinates:
\begin{align}
\ddot{\mathbf{r}}&=\bigg(\ddot{r}-r\dot{\theta}^2\bigg)\,\hat{\mathbf{r}}+
\bigg(r\ddot{\theta}+2\dot{r}\dot{\theta}\bigg)\,\hat{\mathbf{\theta}}.
\end{align}
In Physics, people will give various interpretations for these four terms. For instance, since $\mathbf{r}=r \,\hat{\mathbf{r}}$, the first term $\ddot{r}\hat{\mathbf{r}}$ is the ‘naive acceleration’ if you treated $\hat{\mathbf{r}}$ as a constant vector field; the others are respectively the centrifugal, Euler, coriolis terms.

In fact, note that since $M$ is an open subset of a vector space, we can introduce a ‘position vector’ field on it, i.e it’s just the identity map. Recall in polar coordinates, this is just $\mathbf{r}=r\cdot e_r$. So we can actually treat $\gamma$ itself as a vector-valued map, and pulling back this equation by $\gamma$ gives $\gamma=(r\circ\gamma)\cdot\xi_r$. So, with $\gamma$ playing both the roles of $X$ and $f$ above, we get a formula for $\frac{d\gamma}{dt}$. You can easily verify that this coincides with the above mentioned formula $\dot{\gamma}=\dot{r}\xi_r+r\dot{\theta}\xi_{\theta}$.



2. Connection 1-forms in a more ‘down-to-earth manner’
We can write $de_r=\alpha\,e_r+\beta\,e_{\theta}$ and $de_{\theta}=\gamma\,e_r+\delta\,e_{\theta}$ for some 1-forms $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta$, i.e $(\omega^{i}_{\,j})=\begin{pmatrix}\alpha &\beta\\\gamma&\delta\end{pmatrix}$. I already explained in the first link why these 1-forms exist and are unique. Now, by differentiating the orthonormality conditions $g(e_r,e_r)=g(e_{\theta},e_{\theta})=1, g(e_r,e_{\theta})=0$, we get
\begin{align}
\begin{cases}
2g(de_r,e_r)&=0\\
2g(de_{\theta},e_{\theta})&=0\\
g(de_r,e_{\theta})+g(e_r,de_{\theta})&=0
\end{cases},
\end{align}
which implies
\begin{align}
\begin{cases}
g(\alpha e_r+\beta e_{\theta}\,e_r)&=0\\
g(\gamma e_r+\delta e_{\theta},e_{\theta})&=0\\
g(\alpha e_r+\beta e_{\theta}\,e_{\theta})+
g(e_r,\gamma e_r+\delta e_{\theta})&=0
\end{cases},
\end{align}
and so using orthonormality, we get
\begin{align}
\begin{cases}
\alpha&=0\\
\delta&=0\\
\beta+\gamma&=0
\end{cases}.
\end{align}
So, we see from down-to-earth calculations that orthonormality implies that the connection 1-forms are skew-symmetric; $(\omega^{i}_{\,j})
=\begin{pmatrix}
0&\beta\\
-\beta&0
\end{pmatrix}$. Now, on the one hand, we can introduce the position vector field $\mathbf{r}=r\,e_r$, so differentiating this gives
\begin{align}
d\mathbf{r}&=dr\,e_r+r(-\beta\,e_{\theta})=dr\,e_r-r\beta\,e_{\theta}.\tag{$1$}
\end{align}
On the other hand, $d\mathbf{r}$ is literally just the identity mapping on the tangent bundle $TM$, and we know that in any coordinate system $(U,(x^1,\dots, x^n))$ we have that for any tangent vector $v\in T_pM$, $v=(dx^i)_p(v)\cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}(p)$. So, in our situation, (and omitting the arguments)
\begin{align}
d\mathbf{r}&=dr\,\frac{\partial}{\partial r}+d\theta\,\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\\
&=dr\,e_r+r\,d\theta\,e_{\theta}.\tag{$2$}
\end{align}
Comparing the two equations $(1)$ and $(2)$ we see that $\beta=-d\theta$, and thus we get as before $(\omega^{i}_{\,j})= \begin{pmatrix}
0&-d\theta\\
d\theta&0
\end{pmatrix}$. I want to point out that this approach of comparing the expressions of $d\mathbf{r}$ by first introducing a position vector field (or equivalently, by requiring that $d\text{id}_{TM}=0$) is equivalent to requiring that the connection be torsion free (indeed, one of the definitions of the torsion is as the exterior covariant derivative of the identity mapping of the tangent bundle: $T=d_{\nabla}(\text{id}_{TM})$); and in fact the Cartan structure equation I wrote above is a consequence of writing $d\mathbf{r}=\epsilon^i\,e_i$ and then writing out the condition $d^2\mathbf{r}=0$.
So, once again, the way we found the connection 1-forms is via orthonormality of the frame, and by invoking the torsion-free nature of the Levi-Civita connection (without using those words). From here, we get the same formulae for $dX,\dot{\gamma}$ and the acceleration of a curve $\gamma$.

3. Connection 1-forms in the most down-to-earth manner.
The final approach, and also the most down-to-earth approach, and perhaps the one you’ll encounter most often in Physics, is to change basis, compute derivatives there, then undo the change of basis. The  benefit of this is that you don’t need to know the structure equations or the importance of metric-compatibility; as long as you know the connection 1-forms in one frame, you can change frames and grind out the algebra. The drawback of this is that we have to first have a frame where we know the connection 1-forms and then change frames (and finally undo it); so this is of course inefficient in all but the simplest examples.
Let $e_1,e_2$ be the (constant vector fields corresponding to the) standard basis of $\Bbb{R}^2$. Then, on $U$, we can relate $e_r,e_{\theta}$ to $e_1,e_2$ by the formulae
\begin{align}
e_r&=\cos\theta \,e_1+\sin\theta\, e_2,\quad\text{and}\quad e_{\theta}=-\sin\theta\,e_1+\cos\theta\,e_2.
\end{align}
Or more succinctly,
\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix}
e_r\\
e_{\theta}
\end{pmatrix}
&=
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos\theta & \sin\theta\\
-\sin\theta&\cos\theta
\end{pmatrix}
\cdot 
\begin{pmatrix}
e_1\\
e_2
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align}
Now, using the fact that $d(e_1)=d(e_2)=0$, we get that
\begin{align}
d
\begin{pmatrix}
e_r\\
e_{\theta}
\end{pmatrix}
&=\left[d
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos\theta & \sin\theta\\
-\sin\theta&\cos\theta
\end{pmatrix}
\right]\cdot 
\begin{pmatrix}
e_1\\
e_2
\end{pmatrix}\\
&=
\left[
\begin{pmatrix}
-\sin\theta & \cos\theta\\
-\cos\theta&-\sin\theta
\end{pmatrix}\,d\theta
\right]\cdot 
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos\theta & \sin\theta\\
-\sin\theta&\cos\theta
\end{pmatrix}^{-1}
\cdot
\begin{pmatrix}
e_r\\
e_{\theta}
\end{pmatrix}\\
&=
\begin{pmatrix}
0&d\theta\\
-d\theta&0
\end{pmatrix}\cdot
\begin{pmatrix}
e_r\\
e_{\theta}
\end{pmatrix}\\
&=
\begin{pmatrix}
d\theta\,\,e_{\theta}\\
-d\theta\,\,e_r
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align}
Thus, we have once again recovered the formula $(@)$.

Some other possibilities.
You don’t have to work out the connection 1-forms relative to this orthonormal frame, but instead work directly with the coordinate-induced frame $\frac{\partial}{\partial r},\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}$ (which is orthogonal but not orthonormal). Then, you can introduce the corresponding Christoffel symbols, which you can compute mechanically for example by starting with the free Lagrangian $L=\frac{1}{2}(\dot{r}^2+r^2\dot{\theta}^2)$, and writing out the corresponding Euler-Lagrange equations.
I don’t particularly like this, but nevertheless, it is very quick for obtaining the $\Gamma$’s, and accordingly for writing down the acceleration. But for computational purposes, differential forms are much better at organizing a lot of the information.

I have just skimmed through your answer and it seems to be exactly the kind of response I was hoping for, thank you. It will take some time, but I'll definitely look into it more thoroughly and maybe ask a couple of questions
